# Normal distribution random variable engine blocks

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

The diameters of cylinders drilled into an engine block vary slightly, being normally distributed with a mean of **12.500** cm and a standard deviation of **0.002** cm.  If the diameter of a given cylinder is within **0.003** cm of the target value of **12.500** cm, it is acceptable.
a) What is the probability that a randomly selected cylinder will be acceptable?

My work:

$P(12.497 < x < 12.503) = [ \frac{ 12.497 - 12.5} {0.11} < z < \frac{12.503 - 12.5} {0.11} ]$

which then equals  $(-0.0273 < z < 0.0273) = (0.4880 < z < 0.5120)$

I then did  $0.5120-0.4880 = 0.0240$

The final answer is **0.8664**, but I'm not sure how to arrive at it. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be a $0.11$ in that denom. In fact it should be your given SD because you are selecting only one cylinder. This gives a z-score of $-1.5$ for the left boundary. Looking in the cumulative z-table I read $0.0668$ Due to symmetry the region that falls outside the required measurement is then $2*0.0668$ and when you subtract that from $1$ (total probability) you arrive at $0.8664

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I see my error where 0.002 should be in the denominator.

Comment: Sure. Now remember that if the question becomes about randomly selecting more than 1 cylinder in the sample, that denominator is going to change. This is loosely referred to as the √n-law for the SD. I am sure this is discussed somewhere in your textbook section Normal Distribution.